# CRC32 (Ethernet) Calculation vs .ZIP/.PNG in Java?

Tags: java, png, checksum, ethernet, crc32

I can only calculate the CRC32 values of .ZIP/.PNG Strings, but not Ethernet related ones. The Java CRC32 class only seems to allow for one type of calculation.

```
    String str = textField.getText();
    Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
    byte bytes[] = null;

    try {
        bytes = str.getBytes("ASCII");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    long lngChecksum = checksum.getValue();
    crc32bField.setText(Long.toHexString(lngChecksum));
```

This is the code I've written to calculate my CRC, could anyone help me achieve the same values as one calculated on this website?

http://hash.online-convert.com/crc32-generator

Just as an example,

"hello world" =

7813f744 (website)

D4A1185  (My Code)

Thanks :)

Comment: Mmm...this gets me the decimal value, I need the CRC's value in HEX

Comment: @Junaid Why? His reference CRC is in hex. Your suggestion gives decimal. What's your point?

Comment: @Junaid You can always delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the algorithm used in the website you provided is CRC32 whereas the one you are using is CRC32B. Both of them are completely different algorithms that is why you are getting different values.

You try the CRC32B algorithm from the same [website](http://hash.online-convert.com/crc32b-generator). It is inline with what the `Checksum` class is giving you.